# Best way to run task on Windows from web server on Linux

Tags: python, django, linux, windows, python-3.x

I have a task written in Python with a 1-2 minute run-time that I want to run on-demand. The requests would come In very small volumes from a Django server on Linux. The return would be a file.

Usually, I'd use a queue system like Celery. But, this task can only be run on Windows.

What is the best way to make this happen?

Remotely execute the task by establishing an SSH session? 
Still use Celery, go through a lot of workarounds to get it to work on Windows (seems messy)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could think of 5 solutions which do not require ssh

I didn't talk about authentication in my solutions you should implement something based on chosen solution

Solution 1:

- write a simple flask/django app for windows server which runs the task and returns response
- in your linux server send a request to windows and get data
- linux server can make this call using celery so you wouldn't bother about 2/3 minute wait

Solution 2:

- write a simple flask/django app for windows server which calls a celery task in back ground

  - this app should return the url of result file
- celery task creates a file which contains the result
- serve this file with nginx (or a windows based static file server, I don't know windows)
- send a request from linux server to windows to get result (if file doesn't exists it means result is not ready yet)

Solution 3:

- write a simple flask/django app for windows server which calls a celery task in back ground

  - this app returns a random id for given request
- from your linux server send requests to windows app with task id
- when task is finished windows app returns result

Solution 4:

- write a simple flask/django app for windows server which calls a celery task in back ground
- add an endpoint to your linux django app for uploading data
- when windows app finishes processing it uploads data to linux django app

Solution 5:

- solution 4 but your linux django app is not for uploading data. it only sets a boolean which mean task is done
- if task is done linux server send a request to winsows server to get data (this request contains the task id)

Comment: Thanks, this is a better set of jumping off points for me. I realized that I can also have a logical shared space between these two servers because they are VMs, which will make serving the file a bit easier.